# How to use python 2 for certain installed application while keeping python 3 as default

Tags: command-line, python, terminator

I am Ubuntu 18. I am using terminator as my terminal client. Terminator runs using python 2. I am using Python 3.9 as default since several application in my machine require that version. But when python 3.9 is set as default, I am unable to launch terminator. The error thrown is as follows:

File "/usr/bin/terminator", line 123
except (KeyError,ValueError), ex:
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Is there a way to configure terminator to use python 2 while keeping python 3.9 as the default version. The option I could think of was by editing the terminator.desktop file and changing the launch command to use python 2. Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: Why are you using an old version of terminator, when [terminator 2](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator) is using python 3?

Comment: Ubuntu 18?    Ubuntu desktop and server releases have a *yy.mm* format, and whilst specialist snap based releases like Ubuntu Core 18 for IoT appliances do use a *yy* format there are none titled just Ubuntu 18.  Please clarify your release as there is no Ubuntu 18.   *Ubuntu has used year only releases since 2016 to specify snap only releases so are you talking about a Ubuntu Core or other like release?*

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative you can install [newer version](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/terminator) of Terminator from Ubuntu 20.04 LTS by:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/terminator/terminator_1.91-4ubuntu1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./terminator_1.91-4ubuntu1_all.deb
```

or from upcoming 21.04:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/t/terminator/terminator_2.1.0-1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./terminator_2.1.0-1_all.deb
```

It depends on Python 3, so should work with it.

Comment: Or install an [even newer version](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/terminator_2.1.0-1_all.deb.html), after checking dependencies are ok.

Comment: @ArturMeinild, right. Just checked https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/terminator - it installs and works on 18.04 LTS without problems.